PathCurvers from startpoint
I have a problem with the curves in my path. I think it comes from the starting point x and starting point y. these have no curves. I had previously added an extra path and then tried to manipulate it together with startX and startY. However, that didn't work and I had the same result. Maybe someone can give me a working hint. So it's actually just about the two points that are "pointy".

import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Shapes
import QtQuick.Effects
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Timeline 1.0
import QtMultimedia
import QtCore

Item {
    id: polarChart
    width: 300
    height: 300
    layer.smooth: false

    property real caloriesPercent: 0.9
    property real carbsPercent: 0.64
    property real proteinPercent: 0.6
    property real fatPercent: 0.8

    EllipseItem {
        id: backgroundEllipse
        anchors.fill: parent

        strokeStyle: 0

        gradient: RadialGradient {
            centerX: backgroundEllipse.width; centerY: backgroundEllipse.height
            centerRadius: backgroundEllipse.height;
            focalX: centerX; focalY: centerY
            GradientStop { position: 0; color: Constants.colors.light500 }
            GradientStop { position: 1; color: Constants.colors.dark300 }
        }
        layer.enabled: true
        layer.effect: MultiEffect {
            autoPaddingEnabled: true
            blurMax: 32
            blur: 1
            blurEnabled: true
        }
    }
    EllipseItem {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: (ellipseChartLayer.width/12)
        antialiasing: true
        layer.mipmap: true
        strokeStyle: 0

        gradient: RadialGradient {
            centerX: backgroundEllipse.width; centerY: backgroundEllipse.height
            centerRadius: backgroundEllipse.height;
            focalX: centerX; focalY: centerY
            GradientStop { position: 0.5; color: Constants.colors.dark300 }
            GradientStop { position: 1; color: Constants.colors.dark100 }
        }
        layer.enabled: true
        layer.smooth: true

        layer.effect: MultiEffect {
            shadowOpacity: 0.3
            shadowHorizontalOffset: -5
            shadowVerticalOffset: -5
            autoPaddingEnabled: true
            shadowColor:  Constants.colors.dark400
            shadowBlur: 0.6
            shadowScale: 1.02
            shadowEnabled: true

        }
    }

    Item {
        id: innerItem
        anchors.fill: parent
        Repeater {
            model: [{name:"Fat"},
                {name: "Calories"},
                {name: "Carbs"},
                {name: "Protein"}, ]
            Label {
                color: Constants.colors.dark500
                text: modelData.name
                rotation: index * 90
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.margins: -24
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            }
        }


        Item {
            id: ellipseChartLayer

            width: 250
            height: 250
            anchors.centerIn: parent

            property real cx: ellipseChartLayer.width / 2
            property real cy: ellipseChartLayer.height / 2

            property real a: ellipseChartLayer.width / 2
            property real b: ellipseChartLayer.height / 2

            function pointAtAngle(angle) {
                var radiant = angle * Math.PI / 180;
                var x = cx + a * Math.cos(radiant);
                var y = cy + b * Math.sin(radiant);
                return { x: x, y: y };
            }


            Repeater {
                id: repeater
                model: 4
                EllipseItem {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    antialiasing: true
                    anchors.margins: index * (ellipseChartLayer.width/8)
                    strokeWidth: 1
                    fillColor: "transparent"
                    strokeColor: Constants.colors.dark500
                }
            }
        }

        Shape {
            id: polarChartControls
            width: ellipseChartLayer.width
            height: ellipseChartLayer.height
            anchors.centerIn: ellipseChartLayer
            ShapePath {
                id: caloriesPath
                strokeColor: Constants.colors.dark500
                startX: ellipseChartLayer.cx; startY: ellipseChartLayer.cy
                PathLine { x: ellipseChartLayer.pointAtAngle(0).x ; y: ellipseChartLayer.pointAtAngle(0).y }
            }
            ShapePath {
                id: bottomRightPath
                strokeColor: "transparent"
                startX: ellipseChartLayer.cx; startY: ellipseChartLayer.cy
                PathLine { x: ellipseChartLayer.pointAtAngle(45).x ; y: ellipseChartLayer.pointAtAngle(45).y }
            }
            ShapePath {
                id: carbsPath
                strokeColor: Constants.colors.dark500
                startX: ellipseChartLayer.cx; startY: ellipseChartLayer.cy
                PathLine { x: ellipseChartLayer.pointAtAngle(90).x; y: ellipseChartLayer.pointAtAngle(90).y }
            }
            ShapePath {
                id: bottomLeftPath
                strokeColor: "transparent"
                startX: ellipseChartLayer.cx; startY: ellipseChartLayer.cy;
                PathLine { x: ellipseChartLayer.pointAtAngle(135).x ; y: ellipseChartLayer.pointAtAngle(135).y }
            }
            ShapePath {
                id: proteinPath
                strokeColor: Constants.colors.dark500
                startX: ellipseChartLayer.cx; startY: ellipseChartLayer.cy;
                PathLine { x: ellipseChartLayer.pointAtAngle(180).x; y: ellipseChartLayer.pointAtAngle(180).y }
            }
            ShapePath {
                id: topLeftPath
                strokeColor: "transparent"
                startX: ellipseChartLayer.cx; startY: ellipseChartLayer.cy;
                PathLine { x: ellipseChartLayer.pointAtAngle(225).x ; y: ellipseChartLayer.pointAtAngle(225).y }
            }
            ShapePath {
                id: fatPath
                strokeColor: Constants.colors.dark500
                startX: ellipseChartLayer.cx; startY: ellipseChartLayer.cy
                PathLine { x: ellipseChartLayer.pointAtAngle(270).x ; y: ellipseChartLayer.pointAtAngle(270).y }
            }
            ShapePath {
                id: topRightPath
                strokeColor: "transparent"
                startX: ellipseChartLayer.cx; startY: ellipseChartLayer.cy
                PathLine { x: ellipseChartLayer.pointAtAngle(315).x ;y: ellipseChartLayer.pointAtAngle(315).y }
            }
        }

        Shape {
            id: polarItem
            width: ellipseChartLayer.width
            height: ellipseChartLayer.height
            anchors.centerIn: ellipseChartLayer

            layer.enabled: true
            layer.effect: MultiEffect {
                shadowEnabled: true
            }

            ShapePath {
                id: xOpart
                miterLimit: 12
                simplify: true

                strokeWidth: 4
                capStyle: Qt.RoundCap
                joinStyle: Qt.RoundJoin
                strokeColor: Constants.colors.dark100
                fillGradient: LinearGradient {
                    x1: 0; y1: 0
                    x2: polarItem.width; y2: polarItem.height
                    GradientStop { position: 0; color: Constants.colors.blue }
                    GradientStop { position: 1; color: Constants.colors.dark100 }
                }
                strokeStyle: ShapePath.SolidLine
                Behavior on startX { NumberAnimation{ duration: 300 } }
                Behavior on startY { NumberAnimation{ duration: 300 } }

                PathCurve {
                    id: bottomRightLine
                    Behavior on x{ NumberAnimation{ duration: 300 } }
                    Behavior on y { NumberAnimation{ duration: 300 } }
                    Component.onCompleted: {
                        x = bottomRightPath.pointAtPercent(polarChart.caloriesPercent > polarChart.carbsPercent ?
                                                               polarChart.carbsPercent/2 : polarChart.caloriesPercent/2).x;
                        y = bottomRightPath.pointAtPercent(polarChart.caloriesPercent > polarChart.carbsPercent ?
                                                               polarChart.carbsPercent/2 : polarChart.caloriesPercent/2).y
                    }
                }
                PathCurve {
                    id: carbsLine
                    Behavior on x{ NumberAnimation{ duration: 300 } }
                    Behavior on y { NumberAnimation{ duration: 300 } }
                    Component.onCompleted: {
                        x = carbsPath.pointAtPercent(polarChart.carbsPercent).x;
                        y = carbsPath.pointAtPercent(polarChart.carbsPercent).y
                    }
                }
                PathCurve {
                    id: bottomLeftLine
                    Behavior on x{ NumberAnimation{ duration: 300 } }
                    Behavior on y { NumberAnimation{ duration: 300 } }
                    Component.onCompleted: {
                        x = bottomLeftPath.pointAtPercent(polarChart.carbsPercent > polarChart.proteinPercent ?
                                                              polarChart.proteinPercent/2 : polarChart.carbsPercent/2).x;
                        y = bottomLeftPath.pointAtPercent(polarChart.carbsPercent > polarChart.proteinPercent ?
                                                              polarChart.proteinPercent/2 : polarChart.carbsPercent/2).y
                    }
                }

                PathCurve {
                    id: proteinLine
                    Behavior on x{ NumberAnimation{ duration: 300 } }
                    Behavior on y { NumberAnimation{ duration: 300 } }
                    Component.onCompleted: {
                        x = proteinPath.pointAtPercent(polarChart.proteinPercent).x;
                        y = proteinPath.pointAtPercent(polarChart.proteinPercent).y
                    }
                }
                PathCurve {
                    id: topLeftLine
                    Behavior on x{ NumberAnimation{ duration: 300 } }
                    Behavior on y { NumberAnimation{ duration: 300 } }
                    Component.onCompleted: {
                        x = topLeftPath.pointAtPercent(polarChart.proteinPercent > polarChart.fatPercent ?
                                                           polarChart.fatPercent/2 : polarChart.proteinPercent/2).x;
                        y = topLeftPath.pointAtPercent(polarChart.proteinPercent > polarChart.fatPercent ?
                                                           polarChart.fatPercent/2 : polarChart.proteinPercent/2).y
                    }
                }

                PathCurve {
                    id: fatLine
                    Behavior on x{ NumberAnimation{ duration: 300 } }
                    Behavior on y { NumberAnimation{ duration: 300 } }
                    Component.onCompleted: {
                        x = fatPath.pointAtPercent(polarChart.fatPercent).x;
                        y = fatPath.pointAtPercent(polarChart.fatPercent).y
                    }
                }
                PathCurve {
                    id: topRightLine
                    Behavior on x{ NumberAnimation{ duration: 300 } }
                    Behavior on y { NumberAnimation{ duration: 300 } }
                    Component.onCompleted: {
                        x = topRightPath.pointAtPercent(polarChart.fatPercent > polarChart.caloriesPercent ?
                                                            polarChart.caloriesPercent/2 : polarChart.fatPercent/2).x;
                        y = topRightPath.pointAtPercent(polarChart.fatPercent > polarChart.caloriesPercent ?
                                                            polarChart.caloriesPercent/2 : polarChart.fatPercent/2).y
                    }
                }
                // startX: 20; startY: 20
                // PathLine { x: carbsPath.pointAtPercent(0.5).x; y: carbsPath.pointAtPercent(0.5).y }
                // PathLine { x: proteinPath.pointAtPercent(0.5).x; y: proteinPath.pointAtPercent(0.5).y }
                // PathLine { x: fatPath.pointAtPercent(0.75).x; y: fatPath.pointAtPercent(0.75).y }
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    startX = caloriesPath.pointAtPercent(polarChart.caloriesPercent).x;
                    startY = caloriesPath.pointAtPercent(polarChart.caloriesPercent).y;
                }
            }

        }

    }

    Timeline {
        id: timeline
        animations: [
            TimelineAnimation {
                id: timelineAnimation
                running: true
                loops: Animation.Infinite
                duration: 30000
                to: 1600
                from: 0
            }
        ]
        keyframeGroups: [
            KeyframeGroup {
                target: innerItem
                property: "rotation"
                Keyframe { frame: 0; value: 0 }
                Keyframe { frame: 200; value: 90; easing.type: Easing.OutElastic }
                Keyframe { frame: 400; value: 90 }
                Keyframe { frame: 600; value: 180; easing.type: Easing.OutElastic }
                Keyframe { frame: 800; value: 180 }
                Keyframe { frame: 1000; value: 270; easing.type: Easing.OutElastic }
                Keyframe { frame: 1200; value: 270 }
                Keyframe { frame: 1400; value: 360; easing.type: Easing.OutElastic }


            }

        ]
        startFrame: 0
        endFrame: 1600
        enabled: true
    }
}




